# Github Multiple Page

Tags: html, github, web, github-pages

i have my own github pages.
`username.github.io`

i know if github pages can having 1 pages like `username.github.io/pages1`, but is there any way to make MULTIPLE pages like this?
`username.github.io/pages/1`
`username.github.io/pages/2`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, and it is the same way.

To creates the URL `/pages1` you create a directory called `/pages1` and put an `index.html` file inside it.

To create the URL `/pages/1` you create  a directory called `/pages` and put a directory called `1` inside it and then put an `index.html` file inside that.

… and you can put a directory called `2` next to the directory called `1`.